# How to redirect logged in user from login page if already login with any social auth in django?

Tags: django

I try this code. In my app only authenticate with Github Auth (login with the only github)

account/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from social_django.models import UserSocialAuth
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout


def user_login(request):
    user=UserSocialAuth.objects.all()
    if user.is_authenticated:
        login(request,user)
        redirect("/")
        print("login")
    else:
        return redirect(request, "registration/login.html")
```

account/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from account import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns = [
    path("login/", views.user_login, name="login"),
]
```

I just want to check if the current user is logged in using any Django social auth provider. If logged in user visits the login page then redirect to the index page.

Answer (score 1):

Please post other relevant codes like **urls.py**.  Anyways you should simply redirect to **index**

```
return redirect("index")
```

and in **urls.py**

```
path('',views.index,name = "index"),
```

Answer (score 0):

why not try to install "social-auth-app-django" for the social-authentication.

check the site below for more details

https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html

Comment: I installed already just want to prevent user from login page once they login via any social auth provider

Comment: you will need to add some authentication code snippets in the settings.py file. i really can't say much about your question,but let me recommend a pdf. check out "Django 3 by example" by antonio mele on this site "b-ok.cc". You will find the solution to your problem in that PDF.